# Tesseract works with other languages, but not Tess4J

Tags: java, tesseract

we are trying to run Tess4J tests that are provided here:
http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/

Tests works fine with English but when I changed language preferences to Turkish they crash. The code that I am changing is:

```
public void testTessBaseAPIRect() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TessBaseAPIRect");
        String expResult = expOCRResult;
        String lang = "tur"; //this line is changed from "eng" to "tur"
        File tiff = new File("testTur.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(tiff); // require jai-imageio lib to read TIFF
        ByteBuffer buf = ImageIOHelper.convertImageData(image);
        int bpp = image.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
        int bytespp = bpp / 8;
        int bytespl = (int) Math.ceil(image.getWidth() * bpp / 8.0);
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, "tessdata", lang);
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(handle, TessAPI1.TessPageSegMode.PSM_AUTO);
        Pointer utf8Text = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRect(handle, buf, bytespp, bytespl, 0, 0, 1024, 800);
        String result = utf8Text.getString(0);
        TessAPI1.TessDeleteText(utf8Text);
        System.out.println(result);
        assertEquals(expResult, result.substring(0, expResult.length()));
    }
```

stack trace of the error is:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRect(Lnet/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1$TessBaseAPI;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;IIIIII)Lcom/sun/jna/Pointer;+0
j  net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1Test.testTessBaseAPIRect()V+112
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate()V+49
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(Lorg/junit/runners/model/Statement;Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+17
j  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+32
j  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+6
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+1
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+40
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(Lorg/junit/runners/ParentRunner;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+2
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate()V+8
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate()V+49
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+20
j  junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(Ljunit/framework/TestResult;)V+13
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run()V+707
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(Lorg/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTest;[Ljava/lang/String;ZZZZZZ)I+41
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+918
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I moved tur.traineddata under Tess4J's tesseract folder. Also it works fine with tesseract when I run tesseract from the commandline. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I added the file that I am trying to test Turkish.

[image]

EDIT 2: 
Full stack trace:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x646a2e00, pid=3256, tid=5948
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract302.dll+0xf2e00]  STRING::split+0x27cf0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0115c000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5948, stack(0x00930000,0x00980000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x05e1d000

Registers:
EAX=0x05e1d002, EBX=0x0680a020, ECX=0x00000280, EDX=0x00000400
ESP=0x0097e03c, EBP=0x00000000, ESI=0x06030de0, EDI=0x05e1c600
EIP=0x646a2e00, EFLAGS=0x00010283

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0097e03c)
0x0097e03c:   cf9c9600 056b73d0 06030de0 64c06870
0x0097e04c:   056b73d0 00001000 0097e08c 02673ab9
0x0097e05c:   00000000 29d140e0 29ce9ad8 00000000
0x0097e06c:   0097e06c 386f7e82 0097e0a8 390fa4f0
0x0097e07c:   65626100 61616562 00000000 0097e0a0
0x0097e08c:   cedf1e2c 0097e0d0 674c744a 0097e0b0
0x0097e09c:   64a628f8 00000000 0097e8f0 64a628f8
0x0097e0ac:   0097e8fc 0097e114 0097e8ac 646c89f0 

Instructions: (pc=0x646a2e00)
0x646a2de0:   88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7e 5d 8b 56 30 03 c0 03
0x646a2df0:   c0 89 44 24 14 33 c9 85 d2 7e 31 8d 47 02 8b ff
0x646a2e00:   0f b6 50 fe 0f b6 68 ff c1 e2 08 0b d5 0f b6 28
0x646a2e10:   c1 e2 08 0b d5 0f b6 68 01 c1 e2 08 0b d5 89 14 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x05e1d002 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0680a020 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000280 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000400 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0097e03c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0115c000
EBP=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESI=0x06030de0 is an unknown value
EDI=0x05e1c600 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00930000,0x00980000],  sp=0x0097e03c,  free space=312k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libtesseract302.dll+0xf2e00]  STRING::split+0x27cf0

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Lnet/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1$TessBaseAPI;)Lcom/sun/jna/Pointer;+0
j  net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1Test.testTessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text()V+143
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate()V+49
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(Lorg/junit/runners/model/Statement;Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+17
j  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+32
j  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+6
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+1
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+40
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(Lorg/junit/runners/ParentRunner;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+2
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate()V+8
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate()V+49
j  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate()V+12
j  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V+20
j  junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(Ljunit/framework/TestResult;)V+13
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run()V+707
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(Lorg/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTest;[Ljava/lang/String;ZZZZZZ)I+41
j  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+918
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x04ec0000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=784, stack(0x051b0000,0x05200000)]
  0x01069c00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4172, stack(0x04c90000,0x04ce0000)]
  0x01060800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3552, stack(0x04bf0000,0x04c40000)]
  0x0105f400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4164, stack(0x010e0000,0x01130000)]
  0x0105c400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4124, stack(0x049e0000,0x04a30000)]
  0x01045800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3604, stack(0x048e0000,0x04930000)]
  0x01044000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5824, stack(0x04850000,0x048a0000)]
=>0x0115c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5948, stack(0x00930000,0x00980000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01042400 VMThread [stack: 0x046e0000,0x04730000] [id=2280]
  0x0108d800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04a40000,0x04a90000] [id=5332]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 485K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K,   3% used [0x246f0000, 0x24719c48, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K,  62% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24c0f7e0, 0x24c40000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24b40000, 0x24b40000, 0x24bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3308K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,  30% used [0x29c40000, 0x29f7b1b0, 0x29f7b200, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2764K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  22% used [0x346f0000, 0x349a33e0, 0x349a3400, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00ac0000,0x00b70000] byte_map_base: 0x0099c880

Polling page: 0x00210000

Code Cache  [0x02670000, 0x02750000, 0x04670000)
 total_blobs=357 nmethods=176 adapters=116 free_code_cache=31891Kb largest_free_block=32657280

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 3.683 Thread 0x01060800  172             java.util.zip.Inflater::ensureOpen (47 bytes)
Event: 3.683 Thread 0x01060800 nmethod 172 0x02748ac8 code [0x02748bd0, 0x02748cdc]
Event: 3.691 Thread 0x01060800  173   !         java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream::read (138 bytes)
Event: 3.692 Thread 0x01060800 nmethod 173 0x02749048 code [0x027491f0, 0x02749a54]
Event: 3.692 Thread 0x01060800  174   !         java.util.zip.Inflater::inflate (74 bytes)
Event: 3.692 Thread 0x01060800 nmethod 174 0x0274a148 code [0x0274a280, 0x0274a5f0]
Event: 3.692 Thread 0x01060800  176             java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream::ensureOpen (18 bytes)
Event: 3.692 Thread 0x01060800 nmethod 176 0x0274a848 code [0x0274a950, 0x0274aa4c]
Event: 3.695 Thread 0x01060800  177             java.io.DataInputStream::readFully (63 bytes)
Event: 3.695 Thread 0x01060800 nmethod 177 0x0274aac8 code [0x0274abf0, 0x0274add4]

GC Heap History (6 events):
Event: 0.590 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4416K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x246f0000, 0x24b40000, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24b40000, 0x24b40000, 0x24bc0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24bc0000, 0x24c40000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29c40000, 0x29c40000, 0x29c40200, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1564K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  12% used [0x346f0000, 0x34877068, 0x34877200, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
Event: 0.593 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x246f0000, 0x246f0000, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24c40000, 0x24c40000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24b40000, 0x24b40000, 0x24bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 676K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,   6% used [0x29c40000, 0x29ce9128, 0x29ce9200, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1564K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  12% used [0x346f0000, 0x34877068, 0x34877200, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
}
Event: 3.279 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4928K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x246f0000, 0x24b40000, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24c40000, 0x24c40000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24b40000, 0x24b40000, 0x24bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 676K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,   6% used [0x29c40000, 0x29ce9128, 0x29ce9200, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2370K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  19% used [0x346f0000, 0x34940a48, 0x34940c00, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
Event: 3.283 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 511K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x246f0000, 0x246f0000, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x24b40000, 0x24bbfff8, 0x24bc0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24bc0000, 0x24c40000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1391K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,  12% used [0x29c40000, 0x29d9bef0, 0x29d9c000, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2370K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  19% used [0x346f0000, 0x34940a48, 0x34940c00, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
}
Event: 3.695 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4927K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K,  99% used [0x246f0000, 0x24b3fc18, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K,  99% used [0x24b40000, 0x24bbfff8, 0x24bc0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24bc0000, 0x24c40000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1391K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,  12% used [0x29c40000, 0x29d9bef0, 0x29d9c000, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2745K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  22% used [0x346f0000, 0x3499e548, 0x3499e600, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
Event: 3.699 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 317K [0x246f0000, 0x24c40000, 0x29c40000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x246f0000, 0x246f0000, 0x24b40000)
  from space 512K,  62% used [0x24bc0000, 0x24c0f7e0, 0x24c40000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24b40000, 0x24b40000, 0x24bc0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3308K [0x29c40000, 0x2a6f0000, 0x346f0000)
   the space 10944K,  30% used [0x29c40000, 0x29f7b1b0, 0x29f7b200, 0x2a6f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2745K [0x346f0000, 0x352f0000, 0x386f0000)
   the space 12288K,  22% used [0x346f0000, 0x3499e548, 0x3499e600, 0x352f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x386f0000, 0x38b79b28, 0x38b79c00, 0x390f0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x390f0000, 0x3977d0e8, 0x3977d200, 0x39cf0000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 3.331 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x24773480 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.332 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x247818c0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.333 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x2478aba0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.365 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x247969c0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.366 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x2479a270 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.367 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x247a6eb0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.368 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x247aad48 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.428 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x247e0b28 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.701 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x2470a000 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 3.782 Thread 0x0115c000 Threw 0x24711a70 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235

Events (10 events):
Event: 3.675 loading class 0x04ea54f0
Event: 3.675 loading class 0x04ea54f0 done
Event: 3.695 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 3.699 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 3.701 loading class 0x04d821b0
Event: 3.701 loading class 0x04d821b0 done
Event: 3.782 loading class 0x04e8de40
Event: 3.782 loading class 0x04e8de40 done
Event: 3.782 loading class 0x04eb9db8
Event: 3.782 loading class 0x04eb9db8 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01240000 - 0x0126f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe
0x77960000 - 0x77ae0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x705f0000 - 0x7062f000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast Business\snxhk.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x774b0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
0x77350000 - 0x77397000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x772b0000 - 0x77350000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x774b0000 - 0x7755c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75e80000 - 0x75e99000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x75ee0000 - 0x75fd0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x753b0000 - 0x75410000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x753a0000 - 0x753ac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75720000 - 0x75820000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75490000 - 0x75520000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x75fe0000 - 0x75fea000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75670000 - 0x7570d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x73340000 - 0x734de000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x75430000 - 0x75487000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75e20000 - 0x75e80000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75520000 - 0x755ec000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x742d0000 - 0x74305000     c:\windows\syswow64\nvinit.dll
0x67460000 - 0x6751e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x647d0000 - 0x64b12000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73f60000 - 0x73f67000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75ea0000 - 0x75ed5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76260000 - 0x76266000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x73ef0000 - 0x73f22000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75710000 - 0x75715000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x71570000 - 0x7157c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6b4f0000 - 0x6b510000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6b4d0000 - 0x6b4e3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6b4b0000 - 0x6b4c4000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\net.dll
0x73bf0000 - 0x73c2c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x70af0000 - 0x70af6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x71580000 - 0x7158f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x70a80000 - 0x70a90000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x70a70000 - 0x70a80000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x70a50000 - 0x70a62000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x70a00000 - 0x70a44000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x709f0000 - 0x709f8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x709e0000 - 0x709ed000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x709b0000 - 0x709d7000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x73be0000 - 0x73be5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x737b0000 - 0x737cc000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73690000 - 0x73697000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x70960000 - 0x70966000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x70970000 - 0x709a8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x64d20000 - 0x64e64000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x770c0000 - 0x7714f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75aa0000 - 0x75bfc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x728b0000 - 0x728c6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x72870000 - 0x728ab000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74320000 - 0x74337000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x74310000 - 0x7431b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1003d000     C:\Users\deniz\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-deniz\jna2263007016168316943.dll
0x645b0000 - 0x647ca000     C:\Users\deniz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Tess4J-1.1-src\Tess4J\libtesseract302.dll
0x64b80000 - 0x64d1c000     C:\Users\deniz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Tess4J-1.1-src\Tess4J\liblept168.dll
0x741f0000 - 0x74293000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.dll
0x72f60000 - 0x72fee000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCP90.dll
0x72c70000 - 0x72d5b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
```

EDIT 3:
This is the final version of testTessBaseAPIRect:

```
@Test
    public void testTessBaseAPIRect() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TessBaseAPIRect");
        String expResult = expOCRResult;
        String lang = "tur";
        File tiff = new File("testTur.tif");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(tiff); // require jai-imageio lib to read TIFF
        ByteBuffer buf = ImageIOHelper.convertImageData(image);
        int bpp = image.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
        int bytespp = bpp / 8;
        int bytespl = (int) Math.ceil(image.getWidth() * bpp / 8.0);
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, "tessdata", lang);
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(handle, TessAPI1.TessPageSegMode.PSM_AUTO);
        Pointer utf8Text = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRect(handle, buf, bytespp, bytespl, 0, 0, 2048, 1600);
        String result = utf8Text.getString(0);
        TessAPI1.TessDeleteText(utf8Text);
        System.out.println(result);
//        assertEquals(expResult, result.substring(0, expResult.length()));
    }
```

Comment: does it happen if you don't run your junit tests too?

Comment: we haven't written any code apart from tests yet. Do you mean the problem may be about the junit tests?

Comment: Honestly I dont' know. But the stack trace shows a lot of junit stuff, so I would deactivate it for the moment and check if it runs without them. Afterwards you can reactivate your tests in the build process and try to fix them if the error comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TessBaseAPIRect` specifies a region on the image. If the region is larger than the image, exceptions will be thrown. Either specify a smaller region or use `TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text` for the whole image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text but still I am having exception. I added the file that I am trying to convert and the stack trace.

Comment: when I played with bytespp and bytespl values it worked! thanks! now I have to figure out how to work with results.